# Display notification at a certain time (API)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, notifications

I have the following problem - we are developing an API for a hotel. One of the features is to book a service(room service, minibar refill etc) for your room. When you book the service you have two options - book it for now or select a time. I am saving the booked services in mysql table(service_id, room_id, TIME, description).

My question is - how can i create a notification in the admin panel when the current time == booked service time? I am using php/javascript/jquery.

Comment: You can create a background service that check periodically (in a fixed time frame) if `current time == booked service time`, if it's the case then trigger notification.